# KnockoutJS: Bind array to bootstrap grid with multipe rows

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, grid-layout

I'd like to take an array like this:

```
var items = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

and bind it in KnockoutJS so that the output rendered is:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-4">1</div>
 <div class="col-md-4">2</div>
 <div class="col-md-4">3</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-4">4</div>
 <div class="col-md-4">5</div>
 <div class="col-md-4">6</div>
</div>
```

This would be straightforward if it were not for the need to close and open a new row every three items. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Thanks...

-Ben

Comment: Do you want dynamic updates, or you are getting the data once?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that `items` will be updated while the application is running:

```
var model = {};

model.items = ko.observable([1,2,3,4,5,6]);

model.renderedItems = ko.computed(function() {
  var data = model.items();
  var times = Math.ceil(items.length / 3);
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < times; i ++) {
    result.push(data.slice(i * 3, i * 3 + 3));
  }
  return result;
});
```

Now bind `renderedItems` to a template that will have two nested `foreach` bindings.

Comment: Thanks Sabof, very helpful. Just to confirm, if "items" will not be updated, I just use a function instead of a computable, correct? And, I've never seen ko.computable. Do you mean ko.computed?

Comment: And, when you say to bind to two nested foreach bindings, can you confirm that the inner foreach is databound to renderedItems, while the outer foreach is databound to... ? Perhaps there's a way that the item returned in the computed would have a subfield for the actual data, and a separate field for the applicable row. (Just thought of this now.)

Comment: @BenjiFB. Yes, in that case `items` can be an array, and you can calculate `reneredItems` once, and store them in an array. No, it's `ko.computable`. Yo can look it up

Comment: The outer foreach will be bound to `renderedItems`. The inner will be bound to rows, and you can use `${$data}` to access the cells.

Comment: Can you provide a link to anything about "ko.computable"? Searching google for "ko.computable" I was only able to find a few articles which reference it by name, but no code examples.

Comment: @BenjiFB Sorry, it's `ko.computed`. http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html

Comment: Ok, that's what I figured, just wanted to make sure. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Sabof, I'm having trouble getting the loops to work. ${$data} causes a syntax failure. Could you update your answer above to include what the data-bound HTML would look like?

Comment: I think I figured it out: The inner loop should be "foreach: $data"